# Adding in a While loop

Tags: java, loops, math, while-loop

i wanted to add a variable in a loop but i don't want it go beyond (on second iteration y would be 200) the x value, i want that y reaches to x but with adding parameter of 100 at first,how i can achieve this?

```
int x = 130;
int y = 0;
while(y<x)
{
   y += 100;
}
```

Comment: If you want y to end up equally x then type y=x; if this is unacceptable then we need more details

Comment: I don't understand what you're looking for. If you don't want to go beyond x, why would your second iteration be 200? Do you want to do 130 iterations of the loop? If so, you should use a `for loop`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments but it's just an example , i have a big number which i want that my second number gets exactly to it in some levels (like adding 100000) because i'm using second value.

Comment: it was a dumb question and i know it! i should just check that if y is bigger that x then y = x;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might just use an **if statement** here. It's simple and well readable, but by far not the shortest solution possible. Here you go:

```
// Define your variables
int x = 130;
int y = 0;

    while(y < x) {
       // Check if y would be greater than x if you added 100 to it
       if (y + 100 > x)
          // If so, we won't add 100 to y. We'll just assign x to y.
          y = x;
       else
          // If not, we can safely add 100 to it.
          y += 100;
    }
```

Cheers! :)

Comment: Your code is literally equivalent to `y=x;`

Comment: In this condition y would never gets to x , i want y that gets to in some iterations,like first y+= 100 then y+= 30 to reach the x

Comment: @Memento that's wrong. `if (y + 100 > x)
          // If so, we won't add 100 to y. We'll just assign x to y.
          y = x;` the y=x will effectively add 30

Comment: yes i think i should do this, dumb question ;)

Comment: I agree. I was so hasty when writing this code that I didn't even pay attention to what it effectively does in the end. Thanks a lot, Cruncher! :)
@Memento: There are no dumb questions. You learn by making mistakes (and so do I). ;)

Answer (score 6):

Change your `while (y < x)` to `while (y + 100 < x)`.

EDIT:

Perhaps you are looking for this:

```
int x = 130;
int y = 0;
int addValue = 100;
while(y + addValue < x){
   y += addValue;
}
y = x;
```

Comment: in this condition y would never gets to x , i want y that gets to  in some iteration,like first y+= 100 then y+= 30 to reach the x

Comment: @Memento that logic will literally be equivalent to `y=x;`

Comment: Why are you not able to just set `y = x`?

Comment: your answer is okkk , i was so confused and i didn't see a such an easy approach.just hope that i would have enough reputation to upvote your answer.

Answer (score 3):

A more efficient way to achieve the same is (assuming x is always positive):

```
y = x / 100 * 100;
```